# Add more events to fullcalendar when dragging starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to be able to let users move some events around on my fullcalendar. And I want to go to server and fetch counterparties' busy times and display them as background events on the calendar when the dragging is going on. However, when I call .fullcalendar('renderEvents', [...]) while the dragging is happening, the dragging mechanism within fullcalendar breaks and stops.

Is there a way to either add events without breaking dragging or some other way highlight busy times that have to be retrieved with ajax call?

The example is here: https://jsbin.com/qikiganelu/1/edit?js,output. Try dragging 'Meeting with Bob'.

```js
$(function() { // document ready
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: '',
      center: '',
      right: ''
    },
    defaultView: 'agenda',
    duration: {days: 2},
    allDaySlot: false,
    defaultDate: '2017-04-27',
    minTime: '9:00',
    maxTime: '17:00',
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Keynote',
        start: '2017-04-27T09:00',
        end: '2017-04-27T11:00',
        editable: false,
        color: "gray",
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting with Bob',
        start: '2017-04-27T12:30',
        end: '2017-04-27T13:00',
        editable: true,
      },
    ],
    eventDragStart: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view){
      // fetch Bob's busy times and add them as background events
      var busyTimes = [
        {
          start: '2017-04-27T14:00',
          end: '2017-04-27T16:00',
          rendering: 'background',
        },
        {
          start: '2017-04-28T9:00',
          end: '2017-04-28T12:00',
          rendering: 'background',
        }
      ];
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', busyTimes);
    },
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<!-- the code from the JavaScript tab will go here -->


<!-- the code from the CSS tab will go here -->

</head>
<body>

 <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, try preloading all the background events, but hiding them via CSS until the drag operation happens.  For instance:

```
// hide all background events by default
.fc-bgevent {
  display: none;
}

// redisplay once "show-background-events" class toggled on
.fc-bgevent.show-background-events {
  display: block;
}
```

Show / hide the background events by toggling the `.show-background-events` class like so:

```
eventDragStart: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view){
  $(".fc-bgevent").addClass("show-background-events");
},
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view){
  $(".fc-bgevent").removeClass("show-background-events");
}
```

Example at: https://jsbin.com/vuvacisibu/1/edit?css,js,output

Comment: I thought of this option, but to implement it in my case, I'd need to preload busy times for every event's counterparty beforehand. And create individual classes for each. It's not the ideal approach for sure, but it's something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I now see the problem. And your mistake is the place you put your  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', busyTimes);` and also the way you write the array, I also changed the ISO8601 time string a bit to be sure.
You can remove the seconds from the time string and write `2017-04-27T12:35Z` instead of `2017-04-27T12:35:02Z` for example

```
<script>
$(function() { // document ready

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: '',
          center: '',
          right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'agenda',
        duration: {days: 2},
        allDaySlot: false,
        defaultDate: '2017-04-27',
        minTime: '9:00',
        maxTime: '17:00',
        events: [
          {
            title: 'Keynote',
            start: '2017-04-27T09:00',
            end: '2017-04-27T10:00',
            editable: false,
            color: "gray",
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting with Bob',
            start: '2017-04-27T10:35:02Z',
            end: '2017-04-27T11:35:02Z',
            editable: true,
          },
        ],
        eventDragStart: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view){

        }
      });

       //this is the new place for the fetching and calling renderEvents
       // fetch Bob's busy times and add them as background   

        var busyTimes = [
            {title: 'Event One', start: '2017-04-27T12:35:02Z', end: '2017-04-27T13:35:02Z'},
            {title: 'Event Two', start: '2017-04-27T14:35:02Z', end: '2017-04-27T15:35:02Z'}

        ];               


          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', busyTimes);
    });



</script>
```

Comment: The way `renderEvent` and `renderEvents` work, is they add more events to already existing ones, which is the exact functionality I'm interested in. In my real scenario I'm calling `refetchEvents` method whenever I need to clean up these "temporary" events and reload the original ones from server using original function supplied into `events` property. (In my example it's an array, not a function, but the idea is the same).

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand the problem at first, but I edited my answer now and the above script is working for me.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I need to add these events from within eventDragStart handler. Also the library takes time in that format just fine.

Comment: You're right, sorry, actually I tried a lot to make it work but didn't succeed it either, it keeps breaking

Comment: Thanks for trying. I got stuck trying it nicely too. I ended up using Conan's workaround: preloading and creating beforehand all possible busy times.